# Exception in thread "Thread-***" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I have a class to read a text file and put everything in an array. Following is the code I wrote and it ias working fine:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PSResidualReduction {

public PSResidualReduction() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {



    BufferedReader match_dataset1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/mt.txt"));

    String[] temp;
    String delims = ",";

    double[][] mt;
    mt = new double[10][5];
    for (int k1 = 0; k1 < 10; k1++) {
        String line1 = match_dataset1.readLine();
        temp = line1.split(delims);
        for (int k2 = 0; k2 < 5; k2++) {
            mt[k1][k2] = Double.parseDouble(temp[k2]);
        }
    }
    match_dataset1.close();
}
}
```

Since the number of files to read is huge, I decided to use threads to make it faster. Here is the code after using threads:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PSResidualReduction1 implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {

    BufferedReader match_dataset1;
    try {
        match_dataset1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/mt.txt"));

        String[] temp;
        String delims = ",";


        double[][] mt;
        mt = new double[10][5];
        for (int k1 = 0; k1 < 10; k1++) {
            String line1 = match_dataset1.readLine();
            temp = line1.split(delims);
            for (int k2 = 0; k2 < 5; k2++) {
                mt[k1][k2] = Double.parseDouble(temp[k2]);
            }
        }
        match_dataset1.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PSResidualReduction1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PSResidualReduction1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

and I got these errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-***" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in some of the iterations. The error is from this line

```
temp = line1.split(delims);
```

I'm sure all input text files have the same format with the same number of columns and rows.
P.S. I'm using netbeans.

Comment: `BufferedReader#readLine()` returns `null` when there are no more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line1 = match_dataset1.readLine();
```

The `line1` is `null` here. The `BufferedReader.readLine()` method returns `null` if the end of the stream has been reached. Which means that your stream would be empty or you have already reached to the end. Try changing the `for loop` to a `while` loop:

```
String line1 = "";
while((line1 = match_dataset1.readLine())!=null)
{
    //  other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the doc for BufferedReader.readLine: "returns null if the end of the stream has been reached". You should check variable `temp` and if it is null, do not attempt to call `split` on it.